# Beginner C++: Transforming index-syntax into iterator-syntax

Tags: c++, list, iterator, intersection

I'm trying to learn C++ with a little Java background, and I am trying to write code that returns the intersection of two lists. I believe I have the right idea conceptually, but am having trouble with the syntax as nothing is compiling.

Here's the code I have come up with:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <list>

template <typename Object>
list<Object> intersection( const list<Object> & L1, const list<Object> & L2){

  std::list<Object> result;                 
  int pos1 = 0;
  int pos2 = 0;

  while (pos1 < L1.size() && pos2 < L2.size()) {
    if (L1[pos1] > L1[pos2]) {
      pos1++;
    } else if (L2[pos2] > L1[pos1]) {
      pos2++;
    } else {
      result.push_back(L2[pos2]);
      pos1++;
      pos2++;
    }
  }
  return result;

}
```

Things I think that I need:
an iterator (I'm sure the way I'm accessing the list is not correct)

Comment: I have modified the title to make it (hopefully) more descriptive, and to indicate that this is a relatively general issue, interesting for future users. I hope this is ok (please revert if not).

Comment: Since you're a beginner at C++, it might be worth mentioning that you shouldn't really use `std::list`... ever. (Not because there's anything wrong with the C++ class, but because it's a terrible data structure). When you just need a container, default to `vector<T>` instead. (That would also allow your code to work with indices instead of iterators)

Comment: Good point.  `vector` is better in most occasions, but I think is good to know advantages and disadvantages of both `list` and `vectors` and if you want to write good C++ code at some point you need to know about pointers/iterators.

Comment: also you might wanna check out : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change pos1 and pos2 to iterators:

```
list<Object> intersection( const list<Object> & L1, const list<Object> & L2){
  std::list<Object> result;                 
  std::list<Object>::iterator pos1 = L1.begin(), pos2 = L2.begin();
  while (pos1 != L1.end() && pos2 != L2.end()) {
     if (*pos1 > *pos2) { //works only if pos1 != L1.end() and pos2 != L2.end()
       pos1++;
       ...
```

`pos1 = L1.begin()` points `pos1` to first element of `L1`.

`++pos1` moves iterator forward, to next element

`*pos1` gets element from `pos1`

`pos1 != L1.end()` checks if `pos1` reached end of the list. You can't take element from `pos1` when `pos1 == L1.end()`.

Comment: The iterator needs to be `const`.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `const_iterator` not an `iterator`.

All the c++ container classes [have `typedef`s on them](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list#Member_types) defining things like the type they contain, and the iterator types, amongst other things.

In your case `list<Object>::value_type` is of type `Object`. So you can say:

```
list<Object>::value_type object = Object();
```

Similarly `list<Object>::iterator` is the type of the iterator used for traversing the container. You can get the iterators representing the beginning and end of the container by using `begin()` and `end()`.

If your container is `const` as in your question, `begin` and end don't return `iterator` they return `const_iterator`. You can't assign this to the `iterator` type. They are different as one allows you to modify the value, the other doesn't.

You can fix your problem by using the `const_iterator`. However, there are a number of other ways of fixing this.

- `auto` means you don't have to be explicit about the type. It does the right thing for you.
- Templates can use generic parameters so, again, you don't have to be explicit.
- The standard library has various algorithms which might already do what you want (e.g. [`set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)).